# How to perform a mapping efficiently (with 18 input tables)

Tags: talend

I have a job in Talend. The target of that job its to transform 18 tables (with 2 millions record each) into one.
The 18 tables share 2 columns.

So, while working I found these problems:

1) I cannot complete the job when connecting the 18 tables at once.  (memory error) My job look like this, but with much more connections :

[image]

2) I tried to connect only the half, but it last forever (8 hours and still counting) -not efficient at all!- :

[image]

3) I tried to split the job into several small ones, but still without success. I am stuck here.

Any recommendation of how optimize this job?

Thanks so much for reading and double thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily have dozens of lookups in your job, if you optimize the way they're used. You can do the following in order to optimize your job :

Instead of having a single `tMap` with lots of lookups, you can split it in multiple `tMap`s like this :

```
           lkp_1      lkp_2       lkp_3            lkp_y
             |          |          |                |
Source --- tMap_1 --- tMap_2 --- tMap_3 ---... --- tMap_x --- target
```

This is not mandatory but this way you can easily modify your lookups.

Next, in order to optimize memory use, you can take a look the "`reload at each row`" option of `tMap`. Instead of using the default "`load at once`" which loads your lookup table in memory, you can use "`reload at each row`" in order to executre the lookup query for the current row :

[image]

In your lookup query, you have access to a global variable defined in your tMap, for instance : `(Integer)globalMap.get("myLookupKey")`, in order to filter your data on the database side and only return the value that matches your lookup key.

Here is a detailed [example](https://help.talend.com/reader/g8zdjVE7fWNUh3u4ztO6Dw/Ll_zYlcDgWNvb7kwSypEQQ).

There's also the option of "Store temp data" for lookups, which optimizes memory usage, as data from lookup tables is stored on disk instead of memory.

Comment: wow! very well explained, thank you! I am designing the model right now.  The link you sent me is very useful. Thanks :)

Comment: I did followed your instructions and what is written in the link you sent me and still does not work.  I don't have any error in the code, but the job never finishes.  So sad. :(

Comment: Maybe your queries are running slow; do you have indexes on the columns you're using in the where clause ?

Comment: i tried to create index but I wasn't successful either.  What I did at the end was to split the job in several parts and running it separately.  So instead of having one job I made 5.  This definitively  worked!